# Mi expresión regular no funciona

Tags: javascript, regex

¿Me pueden decir que hace esta expresión regular?:

```
const regexText = /[0-9]|\.|,|\/|\\/gi;
```

Necesito crear la misma, pero ponerle un mínimo y un máximo de caracteres.

Es decir, necesito que el campo solo se complete con **LETRAS**, sin números y su mínimo sea 3, intenté varias pruebas pero nada me funcionó.

Con este código funciona:

```
/[0-9]|\.|,|\/|\\/gi;
```

pero necesito agregar un mínimo.

Comment: Lo que buscas es que sean solo letras o que sean solo números?
me perdí en la redacción

Comment: Tu expresión regular no coincide en nada con lo que estás buscando... si quieres que permita solo letras, deberías usar `[a-zA-Z]` y para una longitud con `{3}`...

Comment: ¿Qué hace esa expresión? Confunde! Porque está horrendamente armada y no te recomendaría usarla nunca

Comment: Actualmente esta pregunta incluye múltiples preguntas en una. Debería centrarse en un solo problema.

Answer (score 4):

Podrías usar esta expresión regular:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$
```

En donde verifica que todos los caracteres sean alfabéticos y que su longitud sea mínimo de 3, ejemplo:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$" value="ho" required> <!-- texto con longitud de menos de 3 => incorrecto -->
  <input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$" value="hol3" required> <!-- texto con números => incorrecto -->
  <input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$" value="1234" required> <!-- solo números => incorrecto -->
  <input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$" value="hola" required> <!-- texto con longitud de más de 3 => correcto -->
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

La expresión `[0-9]|\.|,|\/|\\/gi` significa lo siguiente:

```
[0-9]: captura un dígito. Los corchetes indican cualquier carácter que está encerrado entre ellos. El guión sirve para expresar un rango. [0-9] es lo mismo que [0123456789]. Es decir cualquiera de ellos.

\\.   : captura un punto. El slash es para indicar que queremos el punto como tal.

\|    : O

\\,     : una coma

\|    : o

\\\/   : un slash

\|    : o

\\\   : un slash invertdo
```

Es decir, captura un número o un punto o una coma o un slash esten donde esten.

Por ejemplo:

```
1.          Captura 1.
1.a.        captura 1..
1/          captura 1/
hola1,abc.  captura 1,.
1:hola.     captura el 1.
a.          Captura el punto
Hola.,qu/e tal       captura el . La , y el slash
```

Las expresiones regulares tienen cuantificadores que indican la veces que debe evaluarse el elemento. Estos son:

`+` indica una o veces, es decir al menos uno de ellos

`*` indica 0 o más veces, es decir puede como no puede venir

`{n}` indica que deben haber exactamente *n* elementos

`{n,m}` indican que debe haber *n* elementos como mínimo hasta *m* como máximo. *n* y*m* son números.

`{n,}`  indica como mínimo *n* elementos hasta infinito.

Ejemplos:

```
estos 3 ejemplos son de demostración (JCGD2023)



/[a-zA-Z]+

estos
ejemplos
son
de
demostraci
n
JCGD

/[a-zA-Záéíóú]+/gm

estos
ejemplos
son
de
demostración
JCGD

*** observa las vocales acentuadas con respecto al anterior) ***

/[a-zA-Z]{3,}/gm
estos
ejemplos
son
demostraci
JCGD



/[a-zA-Z]{3,5}/gm
estos
ejemp
los
son
demos
traci
JCGD

/[a-zA-Z]{5}/gm
estos
ejemp
demos
traci

/[a-zA-Z]{5,8}/gm

estos
ejemplos
demostra





/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/gm
estos
3
ejemplos
son
de
demostraci
n
JCGD2023


[0-9]

3
2
0
2
3

/[0-9]+/
3
2023


/[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]+/gm

CGD2023
```

En tu caso, no te sirve la expresión que pusiste por lo explicado anteriormente. Si quieres una expresión que sólo admita 3 letras tendrías como en uno de los ejemplos hacer:

`[a-zA-Z]{3,}`

Sin embargo, no es suficiente para responder  porque como observarás en unos de los ejemplos te toma 3 o mas  letras estén donde estén, por lo tanto, respondiendo a tu pregunta,  tienes que utilizar los indicadores posicionalea:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$
```

*^* indica desde el inicio y *$* hasta el final. Exactamente tres o más letras.

Si quieres profundizar en el tema puedes ir a [aquí](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 1):

A la respuesta de @cris223511.dev le agregaría:

- Una validación en tiempo real con `JavaScript` que reemplace los caracteres que no coincidan con los caracteres permitidos en la expresión regular.
- Los atributos `minlength` y `maxlength`, de acuerdo a la pregunta del OP *"pero ponerle un mínimo y un máximo de caracteres."*
- El máximo de caracteres en el atributo `pattern`

Ya que si se deja únicamente con el atributo `pattern` el usuario solo recibiría feedback al completar y tratar de enviar el formulario, lo cual es válido si el formulario tiene un único campo, pero en formularios extensos genera una mala experiencia de usuario.

```js
function validarCaracteres() {
  let texto = document.getElementById("texto");
  let validador = document.getElementById("validador");
  //Reemplaza los caracteres que no estén en la expresíon regular 
  texto.value = texto.value.replace(/[^a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]/g, '');
  //Cuenta la cantidad de caracteres del string
  let longitud = texto.value.length;
  console.log(longitud);
  //Valida en tiempo real la cantidad de caracteres y cambia el texto y los estilos al span 
  //de acuerdo a las reglas definidas
  if (longitud < 3) {
    validador.innerHTML = 'El campo debe tener mas de 3 caracteres';
    validador.style.color = 'red';
  } else {
    validador.innerHTML = 'Bien, estás en el rango de caracteres permitidos';
    validador.style.color = 'green';
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="texto" minlength="3" maxlength="5" pattern="^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]{3,5}$" oninput="validarCaracteres()">
  <span id="validador"></span>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: No necesariamente es al enviar el formulario... Se puede agregar por CSS o un evento que muestren el error cuando se pierde el foco, sin necesidad de volver a ejecutar otro regex. Ejemplo: `input:invalid { border: 1px solid red; }`